# Mockito not mocking simple class

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I use moсkito in my application for unit testing
Here is the class which mockito not mocking :

```
@Parcel(implementations = {TrainingRealmProxy.class},
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = Training.class)

public class Training extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private int id;

private Date trainingDate;
private int trainingDurationSeconds;

private boolean finished;

private RealmList<Exercise> exerciseList;

public Training(Date trainingDate, int trainingDurationSeconds) {
    this.trainingDurationSeconds = trainingDurationSeconds;
    this.trainingDate = trainingDate;
    finished = false;
}

public Training(Date trainingDate, RealmList<Exercise> exerciseList) {
    this.trainingDate = trainingDate;
    this.exerciseList = exerciseList;
    finished = false;
}


public Training() {
    finished = false;
}

@ParcelProperty("exerciseList")
@ParcelPropertyConverter(TrainingListParcelConverter.class)
public void setExerciseList(List<Exercise> exerciseList) {
    this.exerciseList = convertListToRealmList(exerciseList);
}

....
```

Code where im trying to mock this class :

```
Training training = mock(Training.class);
```

And error that is thrown after trying:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.gangstagym.model.models.Training.
Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.

Java               : 1.8

JVM vendor name    : JetBrains s.r.o

JVM vendor version : 25.112-b06
```

JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server

JVM version        : 1.8.0_112-release-b06

I did not find similar questions and I have no idea why this error is thrown out.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @QBrute i edited the question. 1.8

Comment: @QBrute So do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you try if you also get an error if the @Parcel is removed?